# Why doesn't Java understand the class of the object I've placed in this multi-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, class, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a little game but for the sake of example I'll use objects from hypothetical class Student and objects from hypothetical class Books.

I have a multidimensional grid that I want to be populated by either Student objects or Book objects. Maybe it's called

```
classroom[][]
```

and has four desks:

```
[0][0], [0][1], [1][0], and [1][1].
```

I want to be able to place either a Student or a Book (never both), and be able to print

```
classroom[0][1].someStudentAttribute
```

if I know it's a student or

```
 classroom[0][1].someBookAttribute
```

if I know it's a book.

To be clear, it will be obvious when it is a Student or a Book. I won't need a foolproof way to distinguish, that is to say, I'd only be using ".someStudentAttribute" in a situation in the code when it's definitely a student at that desk.

I read somewhere on here I can create a multi-dimensional array that accepts many types of objects by declaring the variable type Object[][] before the name.

```
Student alice = new Student("alice", 10);
Student bob = new Student("bob", 11);
Student charlie = new Student("charlie", 10);
Book mathBook = new Book("mathematics", 578);

Object[][] classroom = new Object[2][2];
classroom[0][0] = alice;
classroom[0][1] = bob;
classroom[1][0] = charlie;
classroom[1][1] = mathBook;
```

This returns the proper class (class student)

```
System.out.println(classroom[0][0].getClass());
```

This also returns the proper class (class book)

```
System.out.println(classroom[1][1].getClass()):
```

But once I try to print an attribute I get an error:

```
System.out.println(classroom[0][0].age);
```

The error is:

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol: variable age
location: java.lang.Object
```

It kind of looks like Java forgot that

```
classroom[0][0]
```

belongs to the student class as soon as I ask it for an attribute! If

```
classroom[0][0]
```

is not the right way to represent the object in that slot of the array, what is?

Might have something to do with declaring the variable as Object[][], but again the point is to be able to put objects from different classes inside. If I just called it Student[][] I wouldn't be able to put in books.

Comment: As far as the compiler's concerned, the type of *everything* in there is simply `Object`. An `Object` doesn't have an `age`. If you know that `classroom[1][1]` is actually a `Book`, you have to express than information *in your code*; read up on casting. But the broader problem seems to be that this isn't really how to use a typed language.

Comment: You have an `Object[][]`. As far as the compiler is concerned, you have `Object` at **every** index. `Object` definitely doesn't have an `age` field. Would you expect `Object student = ...; student.age` to compile? To be honest, it is very very likely that an heterogeneous array is **not** what you want.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I suspected this based on the error message, but was thrown off when i performed .getClass() and still received the correct class.

what I mean by "i know the object is a Book" is because the code is actually specifically placing a book at classroom[1][1], not that the human reader should infer it's a book. I thought that would be enough for the code to understand that a Book object is placed there.

If there is no way to put different class objects into the same array, I will have to learn more about Java to figure out how to do what I want to do!

Comment: `getClass` works because `Object` does have that method, so it compiles happily and at runtime you do see the appropriate class. But the compiler treats every item in the nested arrays as `Object`, because that's what you've told it they are.

Comment: There is a difference between the compile time type of the array reference and the runtime type of the referenced value.

Comment: In "Effective Java" (2nd edition) Josh Bloch details how to create a heterogeneous collection.  It is probably overkill given you know from context when the `Object` is of the type you want so casting should be ok in your case, but well worth a read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class type of object `classroom` is `Object` and as you are calling `classroom[0][0].age`, `Object` class has no knowledge of the attributes you defined in your own custom class. You will need to cast your `classroom[0][0]` to your custom class like this,

```
if (classroom[0][0] instanceof Student) { // Although it is a bad practice and against OOP
    System.out.println(((Student)classroom[0][0]).age);
}
```

I'll suggest read some stuff about OOP principles and then devise a proper solution.

**Edit:** I may not be clear as to what you must be trying to achieve but here is a sample implementation that might give you some idea. In general avoid accessing a variable directly using on object, rather use getter/setter.

Check out this sample implementation.

```
public class Classroom {

    enum ClassRoomObjectType {
        STUDENT,BOOK;
    }

    static abstract class ClassRoomObject {
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private ClassRoomObjectType classRoomObjectType;

        protected ClassRoomObject(ClassRoomObjectType classRoomObjectType, String name, int age) {
            this.classRoomObjectType = classRoomObjectType;
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Type: %s, Name: %s, Age: %s", classRoomObjectType, name, age);
        }
    }

    static class Student extends ClassRoomObject {

        public Student(String name, int age) {
            super(ClassRoomObjectType.STUDENT, name, age);
        }

    }

    static class Book extends ClassRoomObject {

        public Book(String name, int age) {
            super(ClassRoomObjectType.BOOK, name, age);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student alice = new Student("alice", 10);
        Student bob = new Student("bob", 11);
        Student charlie = new Student("charlie", 10);
        Book mathBook = new Book("mathematics", 578);

        ClassRoomObject[][] classRoomObjects = new ClassRoomObject[2][2];
        classRoomObjects[0][0] = alice;
        classRoomObjects[0][1] = bob;
        classRoomObjects[1][0] = charlie;
        classRoomObjects[1][1] = mathBook;

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++) {
                System.out.println(classRoomObjects[i][j]); // This is how you can print the object content by overriding toString method
                System.out.println(classRoomObjects[i][j].getAge()); // This is how you should access the value of an object attribute by using getters and not directly the variable
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I definitely would like to make sure my code isn't breaking any "laws." I'll just have to keep learning more Java to figure out how I can do what I want to do!

Comment: @Jonathan note that you could also happily write `((Book) classroom[0][0]).someBookAttribute`; the compiler would accept that, but you'd get a `ClassCastException` at runtime. Then your code starts filling up with `if (item instanceof Student) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Java is so called statically typed language in contrast to, say, Javascript, which is dynamically typed.  This means, that type of every expression should be known at compile time in Java.  Once `classroom` is declared as `Object[][]`, expression `classroom[0][0]` has type `Object` and this type does not have `age` field.  You need to either explicitly cast the expression to `Student` like this:

```
if (classroom[0][0] instanceof Student)
    System.out.println(((Student)classroom[0][0]).age);
```

Or change type of classroom elements to something that has `age` attribute.

If you want to store objects of different types in the same array and still be able to access common attributes without explicit type cast, move common attributes to common superclass such as:

```
class ClassroomObject {
    // Common stuff
    public int age;
}

class Book extends ClassroomObject {
    // Book-specific stuff
}

class Student extends ClassroomObject {
    // Student-specific stuff
}

ClassroomObject [][] classroom;
```

Comment: Or a shared interface

Comment: No fields in interfaces, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Ah, that's true, methods only. If the fields were accessed through getters and setters those could be an interface.